# leaflet js: javascript listener to draw circle around a map

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Attempting to draw a circle around a location on a map using a javascript listener. The map is rendered using leaflet js. This code works, but only when clicking on the map layer and not the markers. Is there a way for it to listen to marker `on click` as well and draw a circle around it?

```
// Declare a global variable to store the circle layer
var clickCircle;

// Disable the default double-click zoom behavior
map.doubleClickZoom.disable();

// Add a click event listener to the map
map.on('click', function(e) {
  // If the circle layer already exists, remove it from the map
  if (clickCircle) {
    map.removeLayer(clickCircle);
  }

  // Create a new circle layer using the latitude and longitude of the click event
  clickCircle = L.circle(e.latlng, {
    color: 'steelblue',
    fillColor: 'steelblue',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 4023
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add a click listener to a marker and then get the latlng from the marker:

```
marker.on('click', (e)=>{
   var markerLayer = e.target;
   
  // If the circle layer already exists, remove it from the map
  if (clickCircle) {
    map.removeLayer(clickCircle);
  }

  // Create a new circle layer using the latitude and longitude of the click event
  clickCircle = L.circle(markerLayer.getLatLng(), {
    color: 'steelblue',
    fillColor: 'steelblue',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 4023
  }).addTo(map);
});
```